# batch add a character(s) in the middle of a filename using cmd

Tags: date, batch-file, rename

So I have files (mostly documents) with a file name beginning with "YYYYMMDD - Title of file.etc"
I'm wanting to change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD
I'm wanting to do a script to batch rename since I'll be doing this every now and then.

My bat code so far after a 2 days of research to no avail:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ren *.* ????-??-??*.*
pause
```

Any help or point to the right direction for me to look at would be really helpful. Thanks

final

```
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.*"
') do (
    rem // Store the current file name and extension to variables:
    set "NAME=%%~F"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Rename file by applying sub-string expansion:
    ren "!NAME!" "!NAME:~,4!-!NAME:~4,2!-!NAME:~6!!EXT!"
    endlocal
)
pause
```

Comment: Inside the `Do` portion, save the metavariable, `%%a`, to a variable, `var`, enable delayed expansion, then rename `%%a` with the new name, which will be `!var!` with your date separator, `-`, inserted at the fifth and then the eighth positions, then endlocal.

Comment: Thank you for telling me how I should put it. I'm no programmer and just do research on things. As far from what I understand from your comment.. and help with @wellington's answer


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("*.*") do (set var=%%a) & ren (idk where to go from here)
endlocal
pause

and I appreciate you clearing out other people who helped me answer the question. Yes. I would want the files to end with "YYYY-MM-DD - Title of file.etc"

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59382169), which uses the same methodology, do not use anything from wellington's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are utilising a `for` loop but not using its meta-variable `%%a` in the body then, which makes no sense.

Unfortunately, you cannot just use `ren` for that, because every `?` in the new name represents the character of the old name at that position.

I would do it the following way:

```cmd
rem // First change to the target directory:
cd /D "D:\Target\Dir"
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D-H-S "*.*" ^| findstr /I "^[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]"
') do (
    rem // Store the current file name and extension to variables:
    set "NAME=%%~nF" & set "EXT=%%~xF"
    rem // Enable delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Rename file by applying sub-string expansion:
    ren "!NAME!!EXT!" "!NAME:~,4!-!NAME:~4,2!-!NAME:~6!!EXT!"
    endlocal
)
```

The [`findstr`][cmdfnd] is used here to filter for file names that begin with eight decimal digits that could represent a date. If you do not want that simply remove everything from `^| findstr` up to the end of that line.

[Delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is needed here, because you are writing and reading variables within the same block of code. Splitting the original name at fixed character positions is done by [sub-string expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

(How-To: Extract part of a variable (substring))
[cmdfnd]: https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html
(FINDSTR)

Comment: I suppose if they were using the `FindStr` sequence of eight characters, there'd be no reason to remove the extension and reapply it at the end, so that would only be necessary for any filenames passing to the `Do` which could have any BaseName of less than six characters.

Comment: True, @Compo; as you might already have assumed I added the `findstr` filter belatedly; anyway, I decided to keep the rest as is because of the optional removal of the filter as mentioned in the sentence below the code...

Comment: Thank you for this.. I am trying to figure this out but somehow still get the error message saying `The system cannot find the file specified.` I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Well, have you specified your actual target directory in the code? Have you tried to remove the `findstr` filter as described?

Comment: Yes. I even tried to put the .bat file inside the directory and work from there skipping the first 2 lines of code you mentioned.

Comment: I found what's bugging me.. was the first `set "NAME=%%~xF" ` I took off the x and it seemed to work great! Really helpful. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU.. Last question tho.. some files doesn't seem to be renamed with multiple dots ex... but this is mostly due to other employees with not so elegant naming schemes. Any work around this? Would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code, the first `~x` should have been `~n`, and I forgot about the file extension in the `ren` command line -- fixed now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a function to rename the files to the format you want. You can call this function inside a loop FOR, if you want.

```
set old_filename=YYYYMMDD - Title of file.etc
:: Extract only the first 4 characters
SET yyyy=%old_filename:~0,4%
:: Skip 4 characters and then extract the next 2
SET mm=%old_filename:~4,2%
:: Skip 6 characters and then extract the next 2
SET dd=%old_filename:~6,2%
:: Skip 8 characters and then extract everything else
SET everything_else=%old_filename:~8%
:: Rename de old filename to the new
rename "%old_filename%" "%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%%everything_else%"
```

Comment: The question seemed clear to me! `I have files (mostly documents) with a file name beginning with "YYYYMMDD - Title of file.etc" I'm wanting to change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD` I expect, as can be seen from my comment under the question is that they simply wish to insert a character in two places on each of the file's names, `"YYYY-MM-DD - Title of file.etc"`

Comment: Thank you on showing me how to do it but I'm wanting to just insert characters (in this case 2 dashes) in the filename. Like what @compo's comment said. Appreciate this tho and somewhere in this lies a simple way of what I'm looking for

Comment: Alright, I edit the code before to meet this requirements.

Answer (score 0):

RightHanded,

Maybe you should look at Powershell commands.

The following powershell command replaces spaces with underscores of all files of the current directory :

`dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ","_"}`

Source : https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

You can see how to modify Powershell strings here for example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convert-string?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question, irrespective of the lack of a [[tag:powershell]] tag. The OP isn't replacing space characters with underscores, they're not actually replacing anything, they're adding to!

Answer (score 0):

Powershell will be much easier to do this. Use this:

```
@echo off
pushd "The Directory"
powershell -command "& {get-childitem | foreach {$NewName = $_.Name -replace '\d{8}.*', '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*'; rename-item -path '.\$_.Name' -newname '$NewName'}}"
popd
goto :eof
```